# slideUp slideDown is not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to slide down `description-exp` when the user click on `image-exp`, sliding up others `description-exp`.

I'm working with a Bootstrap template : [this one](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/)

I also made a working JSFiddle [just here](http://jsfiddle.net/ne2ox4q5/) but I don't know where does the problem come from  ..

Have an idea ?

Here is my code :

```
<div class="col-md-3 wrap-image-exp" id="kaiman">
    <div class="image-exp">
        <img src="./img/kaiman.png" class="img-responsive logo-
        experiences" alt="Kaiman">
        <h3 class="logo-kaiman">Title</h3>
        <h6 class="logo-kaiman">small text</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 description-exp">
    <h4>MOTS-CLEFS : Bootstrap3, HTML5, CSS3, WordPress</h4>
        <p><u>Kaiman</u> est la fusion d'une agence de conseil en 
            communication et d'une ESN. Elle rassemble plusieurs pôles 
            (K-Up, K-Service et K-Communication) et offre ainsi un 
            éventail de solutions à ses clients.
        </p>
</div>
```

And CSS :

```
.description-exp{
    background: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 3px #223645;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/ne2ox4q5/1/

Comment: Yes this is it !

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fix your issue, but consider using Bootstrap's "collapse", it seems to fit your scenario pretty well.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$.siblings()` to define `currentContent` and that will get *all* elements with `.description-exp`. You only want the one that comes after the `.image-exp` you're clicking on - you can use `$.next()` to target that one.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.image-exp').click(function () {
        //$(this).addClass('active-description-exp');

        var currentContent = $(this).next('.description-exp');
        $('.description-exp').not(currentContent).slideUp();
        currentContent.slideToggle();
    });
    });
```

```css
.image-exp{
  background: red;
}

.description-exp{
    background: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 3px #223645;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-exp">
    <h3 class="logo-kaiman">KAIMAN</h3>
    <h6 class="logo-kaiman">Intégrateur</h6>
</div>
                
 <div class="description-exp">
  <p>est la fusion d'une agence de conseil en communication et d'une       ESN. Elle rassemble plusieurs pôles (K-Up, K-Service et K-Communication) et offre ainsi un éventail de solutions à ses clients.</p>
</div>

<div class="image-exp">
    <h3 class="logo-kaiman">KAIMAN</h3>
    <h6 class="logo-kaiman">Intégrateur</h6>
</div>
                
 <div class="description-exp">
  <p>est la fusion d'une agence de conseil en communication et d'une       ESN. Elle rassemble plusieurs pôles (K-Up, K-Service et K-Communication) et offre ainsi un éventail de solutions à ses clients.</p>
</div>

<div class="image-exp">
    <h3 class="logo-kaiman">KAIMAN</h3>
    <h6 class="logo-kaiman">Intégrateur</h6>
</div>
                
 <div class="description-exp">
  <p>est la fusion d'une agence de conseil en communication et d'une       ESN. Elle rassemble plusieurs pôles (K-Up, K-Service et K-Communication) et offre ainsi un éventail de solutions à ses clients.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually you're right, but bootstrap is ALSO blocking your code .. I've test and this isn't working ^^

Comment: @Emilien you didnd't include bootstrap in your fiddle. I added it to the fiddle I answered with and it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/ne2ox4q5/2/

Comment: I don't see the bootstrap link in your fiddle. I'll delete it in my project to see what happen as soon as possible ^^ Thank you !